# Youtube embed link - remove title, watch later, share link?

Tags: youtube

How to remove title, watch later, share link in Youtube embed link?
It seems none of the suggestions in the internet works anymore?

showinfo=0
modestbranding=1

Answer (score 4):

YouTube deprecated these parameters on September 25. You can find more information at [YouTube's Developer page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018)

> "The showinfo parameter, which indicates whether the player should
>   display information like the video title and uploader before the video
>   starts playing, is also being deprecated. Following the change, the
>   channel avatar and video title will always display before playback
>   begins, when playback is paused, and when playback ends. The avatar
>   being displayed is new behavior that will be consistent across all
>   embedded players."